# Why does List.toString and Vector.toString return a nice representation but not Array.toString?

Tags: scala

```
scala> Array(1, 2, 3).toString
res1: String = [I@11cf437c

scala> List(1, 2, 3).toString
res2: String = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> Vector(1, 2, 3).toString
res3: String = Vector(1, 2, 3)
```

Logically, one would expect `Array(1, 2, 3).toString` to return `"Array(1, 2, 3)"`.

Update: seems to me like `Array` maps to the built in Java array type—is this correct? and if yes, is this the reason `Array.toString` has to behave like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is because `Array` is a Java object.  You can however use `runtime.ScalaRunTime.stringOf` if it suits your needs.

```
scala> runtime.ScalaRunTime.stringOf(Array(1, 2, 3))
res3: String = Array(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
scala> List(1,2,3).getClass()
    res0: Class[_ <: List[Int]] = class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon

scala> Vector(1,2,3).getClass()
    res1: Class[_ <: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int]] = class scala.collection.immutable.Vector

scala> Array(1,2,3).getClass()
    res2: Class[_ <: Array[Int]] = class [I
```

`List` and `Vector` are Scala classes, so they have a nice representation. Array comes from Java and practices Java's ugliness.

Comment: But `ArrayList` in Java also has a nice-ish `toString()`. The question remains: why where Java arrays not defined to have a better `toString()`.

Comment: `ArrayList` is parts of Java's collections - a standard package that replaces the old Java arrays. Java collections are classes, that implement many useful methods - `toString` is only one of them. Java arrays are not classes - they have their own hybrid types - and they don't implement `toString` because nobody cared about it when they were still used - and nobody cares about it now when they are abandoned in favor of Java collections.

Comment: I wouldn't say that "collections replaced arrays", because arrays are still in use. *Inside* of collections, for example. Also `byte[]` is still very much used, when dealing with sockets/files/...